# How to use ? with a string in RegEx?

Tags: regex

Basically I want to check the following

`www` should **not** be in a string, however this obviously doesn't work as in the following regex any character is basically separated by a |. So w|w|w..

```
[^www]?
```

How can I solve this problem? Is there any easy possibility?

Comment: Which lang or tool  you are runnning? Because in grep,it would be `grep -v 'www' file`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the optional operator `?` here. You can use a [**Negative Lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) assertion.

```
^(?!.*www).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

`[^www]` is the same as `[^w]`.

Using negative look-around can help you achieving that:

```
^((?!www).)*$
```

The above regex matches everything that doesn't contain `www`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
^((?!www).)*$
```